# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag - Not able to find the class that I am looking for

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new at working with JPA and Hibernate so I have some problems with the typequery. I have a function that receives a string and the name of a "Departamento", and retrieves the object ("Carrera") that has that "Departamento" associated with it. In sqldeveloper I have no problem, but in typedquery it has become a bit of a hassle. I am sure that the syntax of my query is wrong, but I don't know how to fix. I would be grateful if someone could help me.

**ClientePrueba.java:**

```
public class ClientePrueba {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        DepartamentosBeanRemote departamentosBean = (DepartamentosBeanRemote) InitialContext.doLookup("EjemploEJB/DepartamentosBean!com.servicios.DepartamentosBeanRemote");
        MateriasBeanRemote materiasBean = (MateriasBeanRemote) InitialContext.doLookup("EjemploEJB/MateriasBean!com.servicios.MateriasBeanRemote");
        CarrerasBeanRemote carrerasBean = (CarrerasBeanRemote) InitialContext.doLookup("EjemploEJB/CarrerasBean!com.servicios.CarrerasBeanRemote");

        System.out.println("Obtengo todas las carreras del departamento MATEMATICAS");
        List<Carrera> carreras = carrerasBean.obtenerPorDepartamento("MATEMATICAS");
        for (Carrera car : carreras) {
            System.out.println(car.getNombre());
        }       
    }
}
```

**CarrerasBean.java**

```
/**
 * Session Bean implementation class CarrerasBean
 */
@Stateless
public class CarrerasBean implements CarrerasBeanRemote {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public CarrerasBean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public List<Carrera> obtenerPorDepartamento(String departamento) {
        TypedQuery<Carrera> query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Carrera c WHERE c.departamento.nombre = :depto", Carrera.class)
                .setParameter("depto", departamento);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag   at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:236)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:181)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:144)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.obtenerPorDepartamento(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.cliente.ClientePrueba.main(ClientePrueba.java:130) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.loadClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractClassResolver.resolveClass(AbstractClassResolver.java:112)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadClassDescriptor(RiverUnmarshaller.java:949)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1256)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readFields(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1746)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doInitSerializable(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1659)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadNewObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1286)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:276)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:224)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadCollectionObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:180)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.readCollectionData(RiverUnmarshaller.java:777)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:653)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.doReadObject(RiverUnmarshaller.java:209)
>     at
>   org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectInput.readObject(AbstractObjectInput.java:41)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.MethodInvocationResponseHandler$MethodInvocationResultProducer.getResult(MethodInvocationResponseHandler.java:103)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:276)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBObjectInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(EJBObjectInterceptor.java:64)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBHomeInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(EJBHomeInterceptor.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(TransactionInterceptor.java:46)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:290)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocationResult(ReceiverInterceptor.java:129)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.getResult(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:265)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.awaitResponse(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:453)
>     at
>   org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:202)
>     ... 4 more

Comment: Did you add all the hibernate libraries?

Comment: I thought that wildfly had all the libraries?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you dont have a hibernate jars in the client classpath.
I mean this dependency:

```
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
```

Check your client classpath and add this hibernate jars.

Comment: ok, thanks you very much. I wll try that.